# Call RMI methods from C++ without remote interface definition

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, rmi

I am writing a client in C++ that uses **JNI** to connect to a Java server running **UnicastRemoteObject-based** RMI.  It works fine if I either use the JNI DefineClass function to load the compiled remote interface definition, or ensure I start the JVM with a classpath containing the interface's .class file.

However, I'm wondering whether this is really necessary- it is not possible query and/or call into an RMI server's interface without having its definition on the client locally?

Answer (score 0):

You need the remote stub, which encodes:

- the target IP address
- the target port
- the target objectID
- a mechanism for generating the correct method ID

... and you can't acquire the the stub without having all the classes and interfaces it depends on available via the CLASSPATH or the RMI codebase feature.

Comment: In other words, no?  This is the conclusion I was reaching, but couldn't quite find a confirming statement.  Is the remote stub generated by the client or the server?

Comment: The remote stub is generated by the server when the remote object is exoorted.